# Auto updating class properties

Tags: python, list, class, oop, python-descriptors

I'm building a `knapsack` class that takes a list of `Items` (another class) as a parameter.
Each item has a weight and a value, and a knapsack should have a total weight (sum of all the `item.weights`) and total value (sum of all the `item.values`).

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have `knapsack.total_weight` and `knapsack.total_value` update automatically when I `knapsack.items.append(new_item)`.

So far, I've tried decorating the `items`, `total_weight`, and `total_value` with `@property`, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to use the property decorators properly or should I be looking at a different implementation?

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self,name:str,weight:int,value:int):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}: {self.weight}kg ({self.value})'

class Knapsack:

    def __init__(self,items=[],max_weight=250,score=None,weight=None):
        self.max_weight = max_weight
        self._items = items
        self._score = score
        self._weight = weight

    @property
    def items(self):
        return self._items

    @items.setter
    def items(self,new_item):
        self._items += [new_item]
        self._score = self._items
        self._weight = self._items

    @property
    def score(self):
        return self._score

    @score.setter
    def score(self,items):
        total_score = 0
        for item in items:
            total_score += item.value
        self._score = total_score

    @property
    def weight(self):
        return self._weight

    @weight.setter
    def weight(self,items):
        total_weight = 0
        for item in items:
            total_weight += item.weight
        self._weight = total_weight

    def __str__(self):
        out = [item.name for item in self.items]
        return f'{"".join(out)}\t{self.score}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you seem to be a bit new to OOP. How about something like this?

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, value, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.weight = weight


class Knapsack:
    def __init__(self, max_weight):
        self._items = []
        self.max_weight = max_weight

    @property
    def total_weight(self):
        return sum(i.weight for i in self._items)

    @property
    def total_value(self):
        return sum(i.value for i in self._items)

    def add(self, item):
        if self.total_weight + item.weight > self.max_weight:
            raise ValueError("that ain't gonna fit in there")
        self._items.append(item)

sack = Knapsack(100)
sack.add(Item('a', 1, 10))
sack.add(Item('b', 1, 20))
sack.add(Item('c', 1, 30))

print('Total weight: ', sack.total_weight)
print('Total value: ', sack.total_value)

try:
    sack.add(Item('too big', 1, 50))
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Update:

A few notes. You could implement the items setter the way you did, but the resulting usage would be counter-intuitive, you would have to do something like `sack.items = item` to add an item. You do not want to define setters for either weight or value, since these are only changed when items change and cannot be changed independently. You could try to make Knapsack a subclass of list, but you would have to implement a bunch of "secret" methods to make it work and I think for a beginner it is a bit too much bother for little gain.

Update on the update:

Mind you that the above is not a high quality cod, it is only meant to illustrate the implementation. For example, I would do `sack.add(Item('x', 'x', 'x'))` and break the whole thing.

Comment: This is great! Thank you. I'm trying to learn more about OOP, and just thought that working on a genetic algorithm project would be a good start. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like you are using the classes effectively. The subclass of the parent class will inherit the attributes from the parent class. You can amend these or add attributes with the `super().__init__` method. In example with the output:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, weight, value):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.value = value


item = Item('Random_Item', 0, 0)
print('Name: {} \nWeight: {} \nValue: {} '.format(item.name, item.weight, item.value))


class Knapsack(Item):
    def __init__(self, max_weight, score):
        self.max_weight = max_weight
        self.score = score
        super().__init__('A_different_random_item', weight=0, value=0)


knapsack = Knapsack(250, None)
print('Name: {} \nMax Weight: {} \nScore: {} \nValue: {}'.format(knapsack.name, knapsack.max_weight, knapsack.score, knapsack.value))
```

This gives the output:

```
Name: Random_Item 
Weight: 0 
Value: 0
Name: A_different_random_item 
Max Weight: 250 
Score: None 
Value: 0
```

EDITED FOR ADDITION IN COMMENT

```
heavy_stone = Item('Wood', weight=251, value=20)

choice = input('Put stone in knapsack: ')
if choice.lower() == 'y' and heavy_stone.weight < 250:
    pass ### ADD ITEM ###
else:
    print('Sorry that weighs {} and is too heavy for your knapsack. It can only hold {}'.format(heavy_stone.weight, knapsack.max_weight))
```

Output:

```
Put stone in knapsack: y
Sorry that weighs 251 and is too heavy for your knapsack. It can only hold 250
```

This way you can create your items from your parent class and use the attributes from the knapsack class

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I intended. I want to be able to add new items to the knapsack while the total_weight of the knapsack does not go over the max_weight. 

I'm relatively new to classes, so I may be completely wrong.

Comment: This is just the basic structure of the use of the classes. To implement functionality to it referring to the max weight just use a function like `if item => max_weight: do something else`

Comment: Answer edited as an example of the weight comparison